# Land cover map of the Netherland

Tags: land-cover, map

I am looking for a high resolution land cover map in the Netherland (ideally for the whole country, but local datasets are also welcome). I know that I can get some information from Open Street map or from the Copernicus products, but I am wondering if there is an open dataset with more details (spatial resolution < 10 m or thematic details that extend the pure land cover components, including e.g. crop types (or groups of crop types), biotopes types ) that I could compare with those products. So I am looking for national/regional product and not global/european products.

Comment: Please edit and add your definition of "detail": how many classes, which spatial resolution, etc.

Comment: Earlier this year the "Land Cover Map of Europe 2017" with 10m pixel size has been published: http://www.esa.int/Applications/Observing_the_Earth/Copernicus/Sentinel-2/Land-cover_maps_of_Europe_from_the_Cloud - while pan-European maybe still interesting for you.